# Using Biopython.Entrez to return pubmed records associated with a list of gene symbols

Tags: python, search, biopython, pubmed

I want to use a list of gene symbols (named t below) in a search in a pubmed database in order to (ultimately) retrieve the DNA sequence of the associated gene. I want to restrict my search to humans only but my current code gives me organisms other than human.

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = '...'           #my email: always tell Entrez who you are

t = ['FOXO3']
for i in range(len(t)):
    search = 'human[orgn]'+t[i]
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='gene',term=search)
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    t = record[u'IdList']
    handle = Entrez.efetch('nucleotide',id=t[0],rettype='gb',retmode='text')
    print handle.read()
```

Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're messing the databases. In the esearch you use `db=gene`, but in the efetch you change it to `db=nucleotide`. They are different things:

- http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=nucleotide&id=7157
- http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=gene&id=7157